# Total numbers represented in IEEE single precision and double precision

Tags: double, precision

How many total numbers can be represented in IEEE single precision format and double precision format?

single precision - 1 sign bit, 8 exponent , 23 bit mantissa
double precision - 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bit, 52 mantissa

Comment: Counting [subnormals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) or only normalized numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Single precision:

23 bit mantissa: 2^23 possibilities
1 bit sign: 2 possibilities
8 bit exponent: 2^8 - 1 possible exponents (1 exponent used for
special cases such as NaN)

So, total numbers that can be represented = 2^23 * 2 * (2^8 - 1)

I hope I'm not missing anything.